# Need to rename project in xcode (checked out from svn) and commit back into svn

Tags: xcode, svn

I am using xcode (3.2.3) for an iPhone project that I have checked out from a remote svn repository (beanstalk)

I need to rename it so that it appears correctly (the App name on the home screen).

I did a Project -> Rename from the Xcode menu.

Now when I want to commit the files back (after change) I am facing following issues.

Under the SCM section in "Groups and Files" Bar, I am getting 3 entries

1. -Info.plist -> This has a A in the SCM column. 

2. .xcodeproj -> This does not have anything against it in the SCM column

3. -Info.plist -> This is greyed out and has a R in the SCM column.

When I try to commit these, I am getting following SCM Error - **"Error: 125001 (Bogus filename) Description: Couldn't determine absolute path of '.' "** 

Also, 

4. Under "Other Sources" I have an entry for .pch with an ! mark in the SCM colum and

5. R in the SCM column against the main project entry for right at the top.

I have tried everything I could. Looks like I am missing something trivial. I am using SVN for the first time with xcode and am a complete beginner.

Appreciate the help.

Thanks

Dev.

Comment: If you still have this issue: What is the output of `svn st` in your project's top level folder in Terminal? Do you get the same error if you commit in terminal (`svn commit`)?

Comment: Hey Thanks for the interest but I ended up renaming the project and create a fresh repository as it was taking up too much of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up renaming the project and create a fresh repository as it was taking up too much of time